# highlight previous selected item when user come back from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

`Activity1` has a `listView`. Clicking one item (let's say item 3) will start `Activity2`. `Activity2` have a back button once clicked will bring user back to `Activity1`. What I want to achieve is to highlight the item 3 when user back to `Activity1` so that the user have a sense where to continue. (May be i need to set the focus to item 3 as well.)

EDIT: Following code works.

```
   public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

     //lastSelectedPosition saved in OnItemClickListener
    lv.setSelection(lastSelectedPosition);
    lv.requestFocusFromTouch();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well its pretty simple. just save the clicked item position of the list to a field when the list is clicked to launch your new activity.

Afterwards in the onResume() method just use myList.setSelection(savedPosition);

as for the highlighting, well focus works kinda bad especially if you have a bit more complex rows(buttons,checkboxes etc) and other ui elements beside the list that can take away the focus. i believe the best way to achieve this is just set the background of that particullar item onResume to the highlighted one and override onScroll listener to just change the background to your default when the list is scrolled. indeed its a workaround but it will work in 100% of the cases opposite to just focusing an item. plus maybe you can add animations on the view so you can make it look really nice and smooth.

Comment: Saving state is ok, but focusing as you described not. It's better to use android interfaces to focus. For example requestFocusFromTouch().

Comment: yes you are correct that android provides the focus to handle things like this but as i said in my answer, from experience i find those methods a bit more than useless. EditText always drags the focus away for example as is the case with other views -> thus my recomendation about implementing his own specific logic for handling this which also has another benefit of the ability to be improved with animations, look and feel, whereas focus can't.

Comment: and saying that you should always use the recomendations and what android provides i completely disagree. maybe when the system evolves a bit more. at this time you can't get a good ui by just using the defaults. they just don't look good. there isn't a single great app out there that uses just what android provides.